# Pass data to a @Finally annotated method in Play Framework

Tags: java, parameters, playframework, parameter-passing

In Play!, I want to log something after I executed a controller action, using the @Finally annotation. However, I need some data from the database I sent to my view. Is it possible to access this data in the @Finally annotated method?

This is the method in particular:

```
@Finally
private static void logSomething() {
    //System.out.println("User: " + u.first_name);
    System.out.println(response);

    for (String key : response.headers.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key);
    }
}
```

How can I pass parameters to this? If I put a parameter in the definition, it's always null (cause how should this method even know what data to pass?).. so is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you sent it to your view, then it will be available from the `renederArgs` map.

So, assuming you called your render method in some way like this...

```
User user = User.findById(someId);
render(user);
```

Then you should be able to access it in renderArgs as follows

```
User user = (User)renderArgs.get("user");
```